# Error When Activating Conda Environment Windows 10

Tags: windows, anaconda, environment

I just installed Anaconda3 and when I open the Anaconda command prompt, it shows me this error:

```
    # >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\owner\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 138, in main
        return activator_main()
      File "C:\Users\owner\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\activate.py", line 996, in main
        print(activator.execute(), end='')
      File "C:\Users\owner\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\activate.py", line 180, in execute
        return getattr(self, self.command)()
      File "C:\Users\owner\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\activate.py", line 154, in activate
        builder_result = self.build_activate(self.env_name_or_prefix)
      File "C:\Users\owner\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\activate.py", line 288, in build_activate
        return self._build_activate_stack(env_name_or_prefix, False)
      File "C:\Users\owner\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\activate.py", line 314, in _build_activate_stack
        conda_prompt_modifier = self._prompt_modifier(prefix, conda_default_env)
      File "C:\Users\owner\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\activate.py", line 639, in _prompt_modifier
        name=basename(prefix),
    KeyError: 'openSim'

`$ C:\Users\owner\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py shell.cmd.exe activate C:\Users\owner\Anaconda3`

  environment variables:
                 CIO_TEST=<not set>
                CONDA_BAT=C:\Users\owner\Anaconda3\condabin\conda.bat
                CONDA_EXE=C:\Users\owner\Anaconda3\condabin\..\Scripts\conda.exe
               CONDA_ROOT=C:\Users\owner\Anaconda3
              CONDA_SHLVL=0
             GIT_LFS_PATH=C:\Program Files\Git LFS
                 HOMEPATH=\Users\owner
                     PATH=C:\Users\owner\Anaconda3;C:\Users\owner\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bi
                          n;C:\Users\owner\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\Users\owner\Anaconda3\Li
                          brary\bin;C:\Users\owner\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\owner\Anaconda3\bi
                          n;C:\Users\owner\Anaconda3\condabin;C:\Users\owner\Documents\R\win-
                          library\3.3\Rtools\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common
                          Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files
                          (x86)\STMicroelectronics\st_toolset\asm;C:\Program Files
                          (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOW
                          S\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Win
                          dowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management
                          Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management
                          Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management
                          Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management
                          Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
                          Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
                          SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
                          Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Users\owner\.dnx\bin;C:\Program
                          Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
                          Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program
                          Files\doxygen\bin;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\Git
                          LFS;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program
                          Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\WINDOWS\System32
                          \OpenSSH\;C:\Users\owner\Documents\Libraries\gradle-4.10.2\bin;C:\Andr
                          oid;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Users\owner\Anaconda3;C:\Users\owner\Anacon
                          da3\Scripts;C:\Users\owner\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\OpenSim 3.3\bin;C:
                          \Users\owner\Anaconda3;C:\Users\owner\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;
                          C:\Users\owner\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\Users\owner\Anaconda3\Libr
                          ary\bin;C:\Users\owner\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\owner\AppData\Local\
                          Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files (x86)\FCIV;C:\Users\owner\AppDa
                          ta\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\owner\Downloads\swigwin-3.0.12\swigwin-3.0.12\
                          ;C:\Users\owner\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-
                          sdk\bin;MSVCP140.DLL;C:\Users\owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft
                          VS Code\bin;C:\flutter\bin;C:\Users\owner\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\to
                          ols;C:\Users\owner\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-
                          tools;C:\Users\owner\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-
                          tools\28.0.3;C:\Users\owner\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\bin;C:\Program
                          Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer
              PROTOC_PATH=C:\Users\owner\Documents\Libraries\protobuf-3.3.0\src\protoc\Debug\pro
                          toc.exe
             PSMODULEPATH=;C:\Users\owner\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-
                          sdk\platform\PowerShell
         PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8
       REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
            SSL_CERT_FILE=<not set>

     active environment : None
            shell level : 0
       user config file : C:\Users\owner\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\owner\.condarc
          conda version : 4.7.12
    conda-build version : 3.18.9
         python version : 3.7.4.final.0
       virtual packages :
       base environment : C:\Users\owner\Anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\Users\owner\Anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\owner\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\owner\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Users\owner\Anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\owner\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\owner\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.7.12 requests/2.22.0 CPython/3.7.4 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.18362
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False


An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.
```

A similar error happens if I try to create a new environment and activate it. Any hint on what could be causing it? I see that that it's complaining about KeyError: 'openSim'. But I'm not sure what could be the root cause. The error message is not very explicit or at least I couldn't get anything from it.

I tried uninstalling Anaconda and OpenSim and installing them again with no luck in resolving the issue. Any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem which is so random that I thought I share it here. It's not easy (almost impossible) to figure out.

It looked like some configurations were cached and had to be manually deleted since even a fresh install of anaconda didn't resolve the issue.

I had to delete .condarc file in the anaconda directory to solve this issue.

For more info read [this](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html).